# CakePHP 2.X: HABTM with Bookmarks / Tags, saving from same form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm trying to build a simple bookmarking site as a project to learn some CakePHP, but am having significant trouble figuring out how to do HABTM (or whatever I might need) for Bookmarks/Tags.

I have a simple form which has the fields 'Title', 'Url', 'Tags', which is used to create a new bookmark.

My tables are set up as follows:

```
bookmarks: id (primary), uid, title, url, private (boolean), time
tags: id (primary), tag
bookmarks_tags: id (primary), bookmark_id, tag_id
```

There's also a users table.

My bookmark model (Bookmark.php) is pretty simple so far, looks like:

```
class Bookmark extends AppModel {
public $name = "Bookmark";
public $displayField = 'name';
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'joinTable' => 'bookmarks_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'bookmark_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

And then some validation.

The tag model looks like:

```
class Tag extends AppModel {
public $name='Tag';
public $displayField = 'name';
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Bookmark' => array(
            'className' => 'Bookmark',
            'joinTable' => 'bookmarks_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'bookmark_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
    );
```

The form on the frontend so far looks like this:

```
<div id="addBookmark" class="card">
            <div id="addBookmarkTopSpan" class="topSpan">add new bookmark</div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => array('controller' => 'bookmarks', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>
            <fieldset>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Bookmark.title');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Bookmark.url');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Bookmark.private', array('type' => 'checkbox'));
                    echo $this->Form->input('Bookmark.uid', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $user['User']['id']));
                    echo $this->Form->input('Bookmark.Tag');
                    ?>
            </fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
    </div>
```

As I said, I'm pretty new to Cake so I'm not sure what's going on here..currently if I enter data into that form and hit submit the bookmark gets created just fine but nothing at all happens with the tag. How do I save the data into the associated join table and the Tags table?

Comment: First of all, what you mentioned to be your 'Controllers', actually are your 'Models', which may of course be a typo. Are those inside the 'Model' directory? Also, could you post the relevant code of your BookmarkController?

Comment: Sorry - the controller bit was a typo, it was very late. They are inside the Model directory. I've since moved on a bit just to get the project working (it's for a class...I chose to use cakephp for the experience of it, though the assignment specifies php - so right now I'm using some terrible cakephp standards and using query() for much of the model work). So my current BookmarkController isn't even taking advantage of the HABTM in the add - I'm doing it manually now. But the original looked something like if($this->Bookmark->saveAll($this->request->data)){...}

Answer (score 1):

In your view change

```
echo $this->Form->input('Bookmark.Tag');
```

to

```
echo $this->Form->input('Tag.id');
```

or

```
echo $this->Form->input('Tag.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Tag.1.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Tag.2.id');
...
```

Just couple of side notes about your code ...

Since you're following CakePHP conventions, you don't need to specify the parameters for the relationship;

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Tag');
```

and

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Bookmark');
```

is enough.

Rather than setting the user ID in the form, which could be modified, set it in your controller:

BookmarksController.php

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Bookmark']['uid'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Note->save($this->request->data)) {
            ...
```